# Apache HttpClient TCP Keep-Alive (socket keep-alive)

Tags: java, apache, http, tcp

I have http request that takes too much time to be processed by the server (about 5 minutes). Because connection becomes idle for 5 minutes, proxy server shutdowns the connection.
I'm trying to use TCP Keep-Alive in Apache DefaultHttpClient to make connection be alive for a long time (Not confuse TCP Keep-Alive with HTTP Keep-Alive that simply doesn't closes connection after response is sent).

Apache http core has following parameter SO_KEEPALIVE: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/CoreConnectionPNames.html#SO_KEEPALIVE. However, due to DefaultHttpClient javadocs I can't customize client's behavior with that parameter: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html.

I did this, however, seems it doesn't work:

```
HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
```

Do you know how to make DefaultHttpClient use TCP Keep-Alive strategy?

Comment: To make it work I needed to set keepalive timeouts. But they can be set only on OS level, not in java code. Here is how I set them on Linux: 
`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60` , 
`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60` , 
`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=10` .
Value is amount of seconds.

Comment: This is not an app level solution!
An OS level solution introduces misunderstandings and documentation errors.
Would be better if we could find an OS level solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work I needed to set keepalive timeouts. **But they can be set only on OS level, not in Java code.** As I know, it's not possible to set keepalive timeouts in Java code.

Here is how I set them on Linux:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=10
```

Value is amount of seconds.