# Apache HTTP client timeout

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HTTP client to contact an external service. The service can take a few hours, if not longer, to generate its response. I've tried a few different things but have either ended up with socket or read timeouts. I've just tried using the RequestConfig to set the socket and connection timeout to 0 which according to the documentation should be infinite but the request always returns after exactly 1 hour. Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tested from multiple platforms and/or locations so it is not a firewall or os issue?

Comment: Few hours? That's not something you solve by extending the timeout.

Comment: @Kayaman suggestions?

Comment: We'll I'd say fix the external service, but I'm guessing that you can't for some reason. Find the person who wrote it and hit them with a brick?

Comment: @Kayaman haha yeah, unfortunately not a option (neither fixing the service or hitting them with a brick).

Comment: @eis I'm currently testing on AWS. I'm not aware of any limitations on outbound requests but I'll look into it a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with general sentiments about not trying to keep HTTP connections alive so long, however, if your hands are tied, you may find you are hitting timeouts in TCP and TCP level keep-alives may save the day.

See this link for help setting TCP keep-alive, you cannot do it in HttpClient its an OS thing, this will send ACKs regularly so your TCP connection is never idle even if nothing is going on in the HTTP stream.

[Apache HttpClient TCP Keep-Alive (socket keep-alive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165269/apache-httpclient-tcp-keep-alive-socket-keep-alive)

Holding TCP connections for a long time even if they are active is hard. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, any service that takes more then few minutes(2-3 minutes+ or so), should be handled asynchronously, instead keeping connection open for an hour or so long. It is waste of resources both client and server side.

Alternate approaches could be to solve these kind of problems.

1. You call the service to trigger processing(to prepare response). It may return you some unique request ID.
2. Then after an hour or so(once response is ready with response), either client request again by passing the request ID, and server returns the Response.
3. Other alternate approach could be, once response it ready, it pushes back the response to Callback URL or something where Client host another service specifically for receiving the response prepared by the server(step#1).